# Subtract query results inside trigger function and IF statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am designing a hotel booking database and want to make a Postgresql trigger function to prevent a guest from making an evaluation without having stayed in a hotel. I want the function to: 
1)make a query to count the appearances of the certain guest and the certain hotel in the Booking table and then a second one to count the appearances of the certain guest and the certain hotel in the Evaluation table
2)subtract the second from the first, and, if the result is less than or equal to 0, raise an exception.Otherwise, insert the row.

I have tried the following code in Postgresql query tool:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_evaluation()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN

    PERFORM 
   (
    SELECT COUNT(guest_ID)
    FROM Booking AS B INNER JOIN Room AS R ON (B.room_ID = R.room_ID)
    JOIN Hotel AS H ON (H.hotel_ID = R.hotel_ID)
    WHERE H.hotel_ID = NEW.hotel_ID
    AND B.guest_ID = NEW.guest_ID
    )
    -   
(
    SELECT COUNT(guest_ID)
    FROM Evaluation AS E 
    WHERE E.hotel_ID = NEW.hotel_ID
    AND E.guest_ID = NEW.guest_ID
)
AS difference;
IF difference <= 0  
THEN
RAISE EXCEPTION 'This guest has already evaluated this hotel';
END IF;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  column "difference" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT difference <= 0
           ^
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know postgresql, but in msSQL your code should read:

```
    DECLARE @difference AS int
    SET @difference = SELECT COUNT(guest_id)...
    .
    .
    .
    IF @difference <= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform basically says 'Run the following SQL or function and throw the result away'. Since the alias "as difference' is part of the SQL it's thrown away. You actually need to select and do so into as variable. So

```
create or replace function check_evaluation()
    returns trigger as $$
    declare 
        difference integer;
    begin

    select
        (
          select count(guest_id)
          from booking as b inner join room as r on (b.room_id = r.room_id)
          join hotel as h on (h.hotel_id = r.hotel_id)
          where h.hotel_id = new.hotel_id
          and b.guest_id = new.guest_id
          )
     -   
        (
          select count(guest_id)
          from evaluation as e 
          where e.hotel_id = new.hotel_id
          and e.guest_id = new.guest_id
        )
    into difference;

    if difference <= 0  
    then
        raise exception 'This guest has already evaluated this hotel';
    end if;

    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```